# I have a date column in a dataframe. I want to change the format of the dates,in that column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in a dataset where the dates are like 'Apr-12','Jan-12' format. I would like to change the format to 04-2012,01-2012. I am looking for a function which can do this.

Comment: You could convert to `datetime` then format from there. But do you *really* need that format? When working with dates in pandas, it's advised to use the `datetime64` dtype. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I know one guy with the same name. Jokes apart here is the solution to your problem.
We do have an inbuilt function named as **strptime()**, so it takes up the string and then convert into the format you want.

> 1. You need to import datetime first since it is the part of the datetime package of python. Don't no need to install anything, just import it.
> 2. Then this works like this: `datetime.strptime(your_string, format_you_want)`

```
# You can also do this, from datetime import * (this imports all the functions of datetime)
from datetime import datetime
str = 'Apr-12'
date_object = datetime.strptime(str, '%m-%Y')
print(date_object)
```

I hope this will work for you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['Apr-12', 'Jan-12', 'May-12', 'March-13', 'June-14']
})

pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y')

This will output:

0   2012-04-01
1   2012-01-01
2   2012-05-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Which means you can update your `date` column right away:

`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b-%y')`

Answer (score 0):

You can chain a couple of pandas methods together to get this the desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_fmt':['Apr-12','Jan-12']})
df
```

Input dataframe:

```
  date_fmt
0   Apr-12
1   Jan-12
```

Use `pd.to_datetime` chained with `.dt` date accessor and `strftime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date_fmt'], format='%b-%y').dt.strftime('%m-%Y')
```

Output:

```
0    04-2012
1    01-2012
Name: date_fmt, dtype: object
```